# What does the @sign do?

Tags: java, groovy

I have seen the at (@) sign in Groovy files and I don't know if it's a Groovy or Java thing. I have tried to search on Google, Bing, and DuckDuckGo for the mystery at sign, but I haven't found anything. Can anyone please give me a resource to know more about what this operator does?

Comment: are you talking about annotation '@' ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a Java [annotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation). Read more at that link.

Comment: +1 For resisting the temptation to explain what an annotation is

Comment: I would rather have an explanation (even an excerpt from the link would do), than a link. Sometimes when I'm in a place with poor internet connectivity, it just helps a lot having to open just SO page to get the answer :)

Answer (score 8):

As well as being a sign for an annotation, it's the [Groovy Field operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-Javafield)

In Groovy, calling `object.field` calls the `getField` method (if one exists).  If you actually want a direct reference to the field itself, you use `@`, ie:

```
class Test {
  String name = 'tim'

  String getName() {
    "Name: $name"
  }
}

def t = new Test()
println t.name   // prints "Name: tim"
println t.@name  // prints "tim"
```

Answer (score 2):

**'@' is an annotations in java/ Groovy** look at the demo :[Example with code](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Annotations+with+Groovy)

Java 5 and above supports the use of annotations **to include metadata within programs.** Groovy 1.1 and above also supports such annotations.

- Annotations are used to provide information to tools and libraries.
- They allow a declarative style of providing metadata information and allow it to be stored directly in the source code.
- Such information would need to otherwise be provided using non-declarative means or using external files.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be used to access attributes when parsing XML using Groovy's XmlSlurper:

```
def xml = '''<results><result index="1"/></results>'''
def results = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def index = results.result[0].@index.text() // prints "1"
```

[http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy's+XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper%20%22Reading%20XML%20using%20Groovy%27s%20XMLSlurper)